# how do i make my program notice if the cin contains a specific word in it?

Tags: c++

Beginner here.

I am writing a program, and I want it to take my input and see if what I typed contains a certain keyword, like `"hello"`, for example.

I know how to make it do something if my input is exactly what it's looking for, like if I typed `"hello"` exactly, but what if I typed `"hello there"`?

It's not exactly `"hello"`, but my input contains it -- so, how do I make the program recognize if that word is in the input at all?

I am trying to make a simple "chatbot" (obviously not real AI, just an idea). This is what I have so far:

```
string ans;

cout << "Hello, I am Oliver, a Chatbot" <<endl;
cout << "What can I do for you today?" <<endl;
cin >> ans;
```

How do I make it check if the `cin`, `ans`, contains a specific word, like `"hello"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`std::string::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find), eg:

```
string ans;

cout << "Hello, I am Oliver, a Chatbot" <<endl;
cout << "What can I do for you today?" <<endl;
cin >> ans;

if (ans.find("hello") != string::npos) {
    // found
}
else {
    // not found
}
```

Comment: thx! would this work within a true or false statement as well? like if i wanted it to check if i said "hello" and/or "how are you?" and display such response

Comment: @bleachedb simply combine it with the `||` OR operator, eg: `if (ans.find("hello") != string::npos || ans.find("how are you") != string::npos)`

Comment: Note that `cin >> ans;` will input the first word only, so `ans.find("how are you")` will always be false. Better use [`std::getline(std::cin, ans);`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) so that the entire line will be read. Also note case sensitivity ("hello" will not match "Hello", for example).

Comment: @heapunderrun how would i rewrite the ans.find so it is using getline to find "how are you"?

Comment: @bleachedb You don't rewrite the `ans.find()`, you rewrite how `ans` is read in to begin with, by replacing `cin >> ans` with `getline(cin, ans)` instead.